# plotting a graph of a diferential equation

Tags: matlab, plot

I have `sym` variable with result from `dsolve` function, 
and I want to plot the graph of this expression.

I think a way to do this is to create a time array 
`t=0:0.001:10` and value array and than use `plot(valuearray,t)`
But the question is how to create value array from my time array `t`?
Am I right, or is there another possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ezplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ezplot.html) to plot the symbolic function that you obtained from `dsolve`.